# How to use Find Contribution to find folk who Donated via a line item on a Membership Price set

Tags: civicontribute, search, line-items

Scenario:

(FT = Financial Type)

A price set is created using eg Member Dues FT and Donation FT. Contribution page is submitted (which is FT = Member Dues).

A person submits the form above so have paid for Membership and made a Donation

Admin want to use Find Contributions to search for all folk who made a Donation. And from their perspective the person above should be listed, but they don't because Donation was a 'line item'.

Thoughts?

Could be an option be added to the Find Contribution interface to 'search by line item'? Other, probably better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the old chestnut about storing financial type on contribution, where it originated, vs line item, where it later appeared, leading to the sort of issue you've described. There was talk a while back of retiring financial type on contribution, which would seem to require changing contribution search to check financial type on line items instead, in the way you describe.

You've specified Find Contributions but as a workaround for now, does the Bookkeeping Transactions report provide what's needed?

Comment: The client/user comment is 'but i want it in the same screen' which I totally get

Answer (score 1):

How about using Fuzion's Extended Reports extension - the LineItem one? It's a great Extension

Comment: The client/user comment is 'but i want it in the same screen' which I totally get

Comment: Sell them the -> but with a report -> we can put it on your dashboard :-)